# Direct Channels in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Is it possible to see which of the users acquired through direct channels in Google Analytics came from directly typing in the url/emails not a part of a chain/were just unknown sources and categorized there? If anything, the last category is the most important for me to differentiate from.

Answer (score 0):

If the channel is direct you cannot understand if it arrives i.e. by typing the url, from an email or from a bookmark. You need to use the UTM parameters in the URL to customize the traffic sources.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en